# How to obtain PID and PNAME values based on PORT ID search. The output should be generic

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

- (Q1) I want to write a shell script to find the process `(pid, pname)` listening on a given port.
- (Q2) Also I want to display ONLY "Local Adress" column when I run `sudo netstat -tulnp`. Kindly assist on this.

I'm sorry as I'm new to StackOverflow. Also I'm a big noob in Shell Scripting. This is what I have done so far:

```
clear

echo "Hello $USER"

echo "NETSTAT"

o1= "$( 
sudo netstat -tulpn 
)"

echo "Enter a port number : "
read num1

o2= "$(
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep $num1
)"

echo "The PID and PNAME of $num1 is: ";

echo $o2
```

Comment: Please, always include what you have already done.

Comment: You want to have your homework done, don´t you?

Comment: Sorry.. I've added what I have done so far. Sorry! New to SO :(

Comment: So students are completing their homework by the help of others? Advice: if so.. try to do it yourself. Please google it, there are lots of tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

Command to get the local address:

1. To get the pid and name

```sh
    sudo netstat -tulnp |
    awk '/LISTEN/ && /3306/ { for(i=7; i<=NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i) }; print "" }'
```

Output: `944/mysqld`

2. want to display ONLY "Local Adress" column when I run "sudo netstat -tulnp"

```sh
    sudo netstat -tulnp |
    awk '/LISTEN/ && /3306/ { for(i=7; i<=NF; i++) { printf( "%s ", $i ) }; print "" }'
```

Output: `0.0.0.0:3306` (which is local address)

Comment: Sir, can you please explain the commands. As it would be very helpful.

Comment: Is it working for you?  you first try to understand netstat command by using man. then read about grep. awk i have used to cut specific field. At my example 3306 is the port number.

Comment: I tried to clean up your formatting but this still needs editing -- both code snippets are identical.